# String function substr in rhomobile

Tags: string, rhomobile, substr

Can i use all the rails string functions in Rhomobile?
When i tried using substr in my rhodes app,it returned an error.
Please suggest a solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rhodes uses Ruby, not rails. You can still use gsub and all the other ruby string functions.
For a link with all options go here:  http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/String.html

Comment: Thanks for the list, substr is somehow not listed in the list, i used gsub instead.